# kurento-room-demo missing library org.kurento.module:markerdetector

Tags: java, video-streaming, webrtc, kurento, video-conferencing

I downloaded sample source code for kurento-room api [here](https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-room). 
But when a create gradle project for kurento-room-demo application, there are a class (`org.kurento.room.demo.DemoNotificationRoomHandler`) still misisng for library `org.kurento.module.markerdetector.ArMarkerdetector`.
After investigating, I found the library is `org.kurento.module:markerdetector` but it's not available on maven repository. So I cannot download the library.
Could you please give the alternative link to download the library?